# How to call a full postback after the execution of the button click event inside an user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, user-controls, page-lifecycle

Okay, 
I have this scenario:

There is a user control with an update panel within it. There is a button within that update panel with proper postback trigger being set. The button_click event is also defined well. I need to call a full postback of the parent aspx page once the "button_click" event is completed. Under ideal case, all the form submission events such as postbacks occur before event based methods are executed. This means my page will first be reloaded then the button click event will be executed. I want something like to reverse this operation. First Button_click event execution then one postback after that on the aspx page(this page calls the user control-> and this user control has the updatepanel with button in it).

Any possible way out would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to change ASP.NET's lifecycle, like the one you described. A (dirty) way of postbacking the parent page is however to put a hidden button on that page, and call it via javascript in the UC. (via ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript)

Comment: Hey, that's a good idea, but I need a proper execution mechanism (barring the dirty ones) because there are lot of other operations on that UC which are dependent on the parent page. Keep on looking just the way I'm doing and let me know if you find something.